# Inconsistent accessibility in object pass as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have This code in SQLServer class

```
  class sqlServer
{
    public string uName,pWord;

    public SqlConnection connection;
    public sqlServer(string name, string pass)
    {
        this.uName = name;
        this.pWord = pass;
        connection = new SqlConnection("user id=" + uName + ";" + "password=" + pWord + ";" + "server=SERVER\\SQLSERVER2008;"
                                   + "database=school; " + "connection timeout=30");

    }
  --------------------
```

and I created object of this class in another class called mainWindow and i want to pass this object as parameter for another classes.One of them are cashier menu those codes are here...

It gives error Error

Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'school.sqlServer' is less accessible than field 'school.cashierMenu.db' D:\Projects\school\school\cashierMenu.xaml.cs   21  26  school

MainMenu part...

```
db = new sqlServer(txtBxName.Text, txtBxPassword.Password);
            if (db.connect())
            {
                db.disconnect();
                MessageBox.Show("Fasasaild");                   
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Faild");
```

### }

Cashier menu constructor

```
public partial class cashierMenu : Window
{
    public sqlServer db;

    public cashierMenu(sqlServer database)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.db = database;
    }
}
```

How can I get out here......

Answer (score 2):

Put `public` in your class declaration.

```
public class sqlServer
```

You are getting error because you are exposing `sqlServer` property as `public` but sqlServer class is not public its `internal` by default.

To do this you either have to make you sqlServer class `public` or make your property `internal`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you declared sqlServer as internal

Here is link for that error: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/997yz02a(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The class `sqlServer` is not publicly visible (it defaults to `internal` since you have not specified anything else). The `db` field is public, which means that it will expose a type that is not publicly visible. The solution would be to also make the `sqlServer` class public:

```
public class sqlServer
{
   ...
```

As a side note, I would redesign the `sqlServer` class a bit, so that it would not expose the `uName` and `pWord` fields publicly.